# google maps sencha touch 2 configuration

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch

Hi I am implementing google maps in sencha touch as suggested here:
[google maps implementation in sencha touch 2 (the MVC way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290406/google-maps-implementation-in-sencha-touch-2-the-mvc-way/18293919#18293919)

However, when the map appears, it first displays a default location (somewhere in United States) and then re-renders again to show the map according to my configuration. How can I avoid this?

```
Ext.define('App.view.Map', {
extend: 'Ext.Map',
xtype: 'map',
useCurrentLocation: false,
config: {
  layout: 'fit',
  iconCls: 'icon-location',
  title: 'Location',
  styleHtmlContent: true,
    items: {
        docked: 'top',
        xtype: 'titlebar',
        title: 'Location'
    }
},
mapOptions: {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<value>, <value>),
    disableDefaultUI: true
},
constructor: function(config) {
    this.callParent(config);
    if (!(window.google || {}).maps) {
            this.setHtml('<p id="maperror">Internet Connection Required!</p>');
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined map view and extended `Ext.Map`, so that view becomes map and when you give xtype to your view, It should not be predefined xtype like map, panel, button, etc..

You should learn [Ext class system](http://vimeo.com/33437222) and try this code.

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.Map', {
    extend: 'Ext.Map',
    xtype: 'mymap',
    config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        iconCls: 'icon-location',
        title: 'Location',
        useCurrentLocation: false,
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        items: [{
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Location'
        }],
        mapOptions: {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(<value>, <value>),
          disableDefaultUI: true
       }
    },
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.callParent(config);
        if (!(window.google || {}).maps) {
            this.setHtml('<p id="maperror">Internet Connection Required!</p>');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! it worked... my mistake was that I was putting the mapOptions stanza outside the config one, thus it was being ignored...

will watch the video for sure...

Comment: @bert ya, that is also the reason i said you need to learn class system.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set the starting location by adding a "center" option to the map's "mapOptions" config.

   ```
   {
       xtype: 'map',
       mapOptions: {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can just override the Ext.Map class and add your own message.

   ```
   Ext.define('MyApp.overrides.Map', {
       constructor: function() {
          this.callParent(arguments);
          // this.element.setVisibilityMode(Ext.Element.OFFSETS);

           if (!(window.google || {}).maps) {
               // do your own thing here
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: this override methods works thanks... I had already solved it before and edited the code but you were really fast it seems :)